# Conversion of a unicode character from byte

Tags: c#, unicode, types

In our API, we use  byte[] to send over data across the network. Everything worked fine, until the  day our "foreign" clients decided to pass/receive Unicode characters.

As far as I know, Unicode characters occupy  2 bytes, however, we only allocate 1 byte in the byte array for them.

Here is how we read the character from the  byte[] array:

```
       // buffer is a byte[6553] and index is a current location in the buffer
        char c = System.BitConverter.ToChar(buffer, m_index);
        index += SIZEOF_BYTE;

        return c;
```

So the current issue is the API is receiving a strange Unicode character, when I look at the Unicode hexadecimal. I found that the  last significant byte is correct but the most significant byte has a value when it’s supposed to be 0.  A quick workaround, thus far, has been to  0x00FF & c to filter the msb.

Please suggest the correct approach to deal with Unicode characters coming from the socket?

Thanks.

**Solution:**

*Kudos to Jon:*

char c = (char) buffer[m_index];

And as he mentioned, the reason it works, is because the client api  receives a character occupying  only one byte, and  BitConverter.ToChar uses two, hence the issue in converting it.  I am still startled as to why it worked for some set of characters and not the others, as it should have failed in all cases.

Thanks Guys, great responses!

Comment: "As far as I know, Unicode characters occupy 2 bytes" this is wrong.  the best simplification is to think "ASCII is obsolete, text bytestreams are UTF8", and consequently always do some encoding/decoding to convert internal to/from UTF8 anytime you get them out/into your application.

Comment: That simplification is wrong, as it assumes UTF-8 everywhere - which is *certainly* not the case. Yes, UTF-8 is very common, but assuming it's ubiquitous is a mistake. The best attitude is not to simplify at all: you should always know the encoding when you encode/decode. Don't assume.

Comment: In this case, I'm not assuming, as I looked at the server side code, and saw that it is indeed send a character packaged in 1 byte (without any encoding). Nonetheless, I agree that a correct encoding should be investigated before encoding/decoding.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx), using the most appropriate encoding.

I don't quite understand your situation fully, but the `Encoding` class is almost certain to be the way to handle it.

Who is in control of the data here? Your code, or that of your customers? Have you defined what the correct format is?

EDIT: Okay, I've had another look at your code: BitConverter.ToChar returns "A character formed by two bytes beginning at startIndex." If you only want to use *one* byte, just cast it:

```
char c = (char) buffer[m_index];
```

I'm surprised your code has been working at all, as it would be breaking any time the next byte was non-zero.

Comment: This could be a little tricky, as we also receive strings from the network via str = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(). Perhaps, I am misunderstanding you response. Would you point me to an example of that. Thanks

Comment: If you're using Encoding.ASCII, you won't be able to handle any accented characters. I suggest you provide more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the System.Text.ASCIIEncoder.ASCII.GetString function which takes a byte[] array and converts it to a string (for ascii).

And System.Text.UTF8Encoder or System.Text.UTF16Encoder for Unicode strings in the UTF8 or UTF16 encodings.

There are also functions for converting Strings to Byte[] in the ASCIIEncoding, UTF8Encoding and UTF16Encoding classes:  see the GetBytes(String) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters can take up to four bytes, but rarely are messages encoded on the wire using 4 bytes for each character.  Rather, schemes like UTF8 or UTF16 are used that only bring in extra bytes when required.

Have a look at the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Test streams should contain a [byte-order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) that will allow you to determine how to treat the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly your goal is here.  From what I can tell, there are 2 routes that you can take

1. Ignore all data sent in Unicode
2. Process both unicode and ASCII strings

IMHO, #1 is the way to go.  But it sounds like your protocol is not necessarily setup to deal with a unicode string.  You will have to do some detection logic to determine if the string coming in is a Unicode version.  If it is you can use the Enconding.Unicode.GetString method to convert that particular byte array.

Answer (score 0):

What encoding are your customers using? If some of your customers are still using ASCII, then you'll need your international customers to use something which maps the ASCII set (1-127) to itself, such as UTF8. After that, use the UTF8 encoding's GetString method.

Answer (score 0):

My only solution is to fix the API. Either tell the users to use only ASCII string in the Byte[] or fix it to support ASCII and any other encoding you need to use.

Deciding what encoding is supplied by the foreign clients from just the byte[] can be a bit tricky.